# Phonegap Paypal Plugin - Environment settings issue

Tags: jquery, ios, xcode, cordova, paypal

I've setup the Phonegap Paypal JS (Iphone - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/PayPalPlugin) which works fine when the environment is set to none - Paypal overlay appears and I can make a test payment - as soon as I change the environment to either sandbox or Live - nothing happens - the event is triggered and no error appears - but no Paypal screen appears either...

My Xcode output appears as follows -

```
2012-12-11 12:21:42.008 ptapp[3108:907] WARNING: You are using a dummy PayPal App ID.
2012-12-11 12:21:44.038 ptapp[3108:907] SAiOSPaypalPlugin.prepare - set paymentType: 3
2012-12-11 12:21:44.042 ptapp[3108:907] SAiOSPaypalPlugin.payWithPaypal - payment sent.  
currency:GBP amount:10.00 desc:Jogging Club  
recipient:paul_1355160222_biz@liquidsolution.co.uk merchantName:Liquid Solution
```

i'm using the following script to trigger -

function startPayment(payAmnt,payDesc ) {
                window.plugins.paypal.prepare(PayPal.PaymentType.DONATION);

```
    window.plugins.paypal.setPaymentInfo({
            paymentCurrency : "GBP",
            paymentAmount : payAmnt,
            itemDesc : payDesc,
            //recipient : "name@example.com",
            recipient : "paul_1355160222_biz@liquidsolution.co.uk",
            merchantName : "Liquid Solution"

    });
    window.plugins.paypal.pay()


}
```

My plugin settings are as follows -

```
#define NO_APP_ID   @"dummy"

/* Get one from Paypal at developer.paypal.com */
#define PAYPAL_APP_ID   NO_APP_ID

/* valid values are ENV_SANDBOX, ENV_NONE (offline) and ENV_LIVE */
#define PAYPAL_APP_ENV  ENV_SANDBOX
```

I've tried the above with Paypal's test app id and get the same - so I've literally no idea whats happening or where to go from here!  Very frustrating!  My only thought is that the plugin is no longer supported/live.

Any advice on fixing the situ or a better alternative method would be very welcome!

Comment: Hey mate, I been working on this today got mine working for the first time. Are you still having problems with it?

Comment: Hi James - just seen this - yep still having problems!  Did you do anything different to the above?

Comment: Hey, I was just informed of this question. I am the new Repo owner of this project on GitHub and will look into this right away. Did you happen to find a solution? I will keep you posted and submit an answer when I get it updated and fixed properly.

Comment: Hi, no still no solution - it works great on sandbox/none mode but not at all on live - literally does nothing.  Any help would be fantastic, handily the project has actually been on hold due to other work commitments - so any thing you could advise would be really useful

Comment: I've got to hand it to you @Paul... After seeing all 4 posts from you about this plugin at various stages I can tell you tried all you could to get it working... I ended up scrapping and deleting all of the old source files and completely re-writing everything from scratch. The project was just not maintained at all by the previous owner. I promise never to let it get that bad again. If you need any help or have any other issues just post an issue on the project's page and I'll do what I can to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin has been fixed and remove of the bugs that were causing these problems. It now lives at https://github.com/SnareChops/PayPalPlugin and has been successfully tested in PayPal's Sandbox environment.